# deserializer does not exist error in Athena

Tags: regex, amazon-athena, presto

I am getting this error while trying to create fixed width table.
The first 7 place holders are for the first column followed by a space and then the second column starting from 9th position.

```
  1 1050174
  1 1050175
  1 1050177
  1 1050178
  2 1050180
  2 1050181
  1 1050187
  1 1050188
  1 1050189
```

I am getting this error:

> HIVE_SERDE_NOT_FOUND: deserializer does not exist:
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe

This create table statement will not fail, but shows the error mentioned above while selecting data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hunspell.frequency1(
  `count` string,
  `word` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "(.{7})(.{100})" ) LOCATION 's3://hunspell/frequency/'
```

---

Update:

This test table works as expected. It extracts **first, second** and **fifth** column.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hunspell.citiesr1 (id int, city_org string, ppl float) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^(\\d+)\\t([^\\t]*)\\t\\S+\\t\\S+\\t(\\d++.\\d++).*') LOCATION 's3://hunspell/myserde/';
```

The data looks like this:

```
1   東京  Tokyo   Japan   33.8
2   大阪  Osaka   Japan   16.7
11  北京  Beijing China   13.2
12  廣州  Guangzhou   China   15.3
21  Αθηνα   Athens  Greece  3.7
31  Якутск  Yakutsk Russia  0.6
110 La Coruña   Corunna Spain   0.37
112 Cádiz   Cadiz   Spain   0.4
120 Köln    Cologne Germany 0.97
121 München Munich  Germany 1.2
130 Tårnby  Tarnby  Danmark 0.04
140 Tønsberg    Tonsberg    Norway  0.05
150 Besançon    Bisanz  France  0.12
```

The example data posted above use tab as delimiter. My file is not delimited by tab. Let's assume the first 4 characters are frequency, the next 10 are ID that may or may not be followed by name of 100 characters.

```
  1 1050174
  1 1050175
  1 1050177
```

In other words how do I import fixed width data in Athena using regex serde?

---

Update 2:

Thanks to the answer, I am able to import the data using this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `frequency`(
  `count` string, 
  `word` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^(.{7}) (.+)$')
LOCATION 's3://XunspellX/stack/';
```

Is it possible to have the first column "count" as integer? Athena is not importing anything if I just change the first column type to integer.

Comment: I changed the serde path to 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'. Now there is not error. But no data is being selected.

Comment: Used sed 's/^ *//g', to remove the leading white spaces. That solved the problem because I do not need regex for this 2 column table. But I will like to know if it is possible to create table using fixed width delimited data.

Comment: You can specify the width of a string column by setting its type to, e.g. `varchar(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received the error message in the first part of the question because you were using a SerDe that is not supported by Athena.

> HIVE_SERDE_NOT_FOUND: deserializer does not exist: org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe

The [Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-serdes.html) list the supported SerDes, so for regex, you would use `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe`, as you found later on.

---

For parsing columns based on length, you should be able to modify your regex pattern as needed. Here are some different examples based on the sample data and descriptions you provided.

## Scenario 1

Two space-delimited numerical columns with possible leading and/or trailing spaces.

```
  1 1050174
  1 1050175
  1 1050177
```

**Pattern**: `/^ *(\d+) (\d+) *$/gm`

## Scenario 2

> The first 7 place holders are for the first column followed by a space
> and then the second column starting from 9th position

```
0000001 105017434786
0000002 105013
0000003 1050177438
```

**Pattern**: `/^(\d{7}) (\d+)$/gm`

## Scenario 3

> My file is not delimited by tab. Let's assume the first 4 characters
> are frequency, the next 10 are ID that may or may not be followed by
> name of 100 characters

Assuming that in this case, your data is not delimited by spaces like in the other two examples and that the third column is nullable with max length of 100, you might have something like this:

```
00201050174347some-nullable-third-column-value
01931050174348
19841050174349another-nullable-third-column-value
```

**Pattern**: `/^(\d{4})(\d{10})(.{0,100})$/gm`

Finally, putting it all together, you'd have a create table statement that looks like something like this for the third scenario:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sample_database.sample_data (frequency int, id bigint, description varchar(100)) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^(\\d{4})(\\d{10})(.{0,100})$')
LOCATION 's3://your-s3-bucket/';
```

Note the double backslashes inside of the Regex pattern here. Per [this doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/regexserde-error-athena-matching-groups/):

> Note: RegexSerDe follows the Java standard. Because the backslash is an escape character in the Java String class, you must use a double backslash to define a single backslash. For example, to define \w, you must use \w in your regex.

Comment: My Data looks something like Scenario 2. But the first column is left filled with spaces (not 0) and the second column is text. This works: ^(.{7}) (.+)$ but not this one ^(\d{7}) (.+)$ I can use string type for both columns in my create table to solve this issue. But I will prefer to use int + string combination (for easier queries) that does not seem to be possible due to spaces at the beginning. Should I use string type for both columns?

Comment: You can still use int for the first column and string for the second column as long as you specify the spaces in your regex pattern. So your pattern would be something like this: `/^ *(\d+) (.+)$/gm`. Using this pattern, the leading spaces will be excluded from the first column, which will allow you to use the int data type.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the user fearerjon the following query works as expected:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `frequency`(
  `count` int,
  `word` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^ *(\\d+) (.+)$')
LOCATION 's3://XunspelX/stack/';
```